# If $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is bijective and continuous, then $f$ only has periodic points of period 1 or 2

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

I have to prove that if $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is bijective and continuous, then $f$ only has periodic points of period 1 or 2. I need an idea please

Comment: Note $f$ is either monotonically increasing or decreasing.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I know that, but how that can help me?

Comment: if increasing.  If $x < f(x)$ then $f_n(x) > x$.

Comment: @fleablood I understand, and what happen if f is decreasing?

Answer (score 2):

Note $f$ is either monotonically increasing or decreasing. Suppose increasing.

Case 1: $f$ is increasing:

Case 1a: If $f(x) = x$ then $x$ has period 1.

Case 1b: If $f(x) > x$ then by induction $f_n(x) > f_{n-1}(x)> .... > x$ and $x$ is not periodic.

Case 1c: If $f(x) < x$ then by induction $f_n(x) < f_{n-1}(x) < ...<x$ and $x$ is not peridic.

So if $f$ is increasing only period possible is $1$.

Case 2:If $f $ is decreasing then

Case 2a: If $f(x) = x$ then $x$ has period 1.

Case 2b: If $f(x) > x$ then $f_2(x) < f(x)$. Case 2bi: If $f_2(x)=x$ then $x$ has period $2$.

Case 2bii: If $x < f_2(x) < f(x)$ then $f(x) > f_3(x) > f_2(x) >x$ and by induction if $f(x) > f_n(x) > x$ then $f_2(x) < f_{n+1}(x) < f(x)$ and as $f_2(x) > x$ we have $f(x) > f_n(x) >x$ for all $n$ and $x has no period.

Case 2biii: If $f_2(x) < x <f(x)$ then $f_3(x) > f(x) > x$ and by induction if $f_{2k}(x) < x< f_{2k-1} x$ then $f_{2k+1}(x) > f(x) >x$ and $f_{2k+2}(x) < f_2(x) < x$  and so $f_{2k}(x) < x < f_{2k-1}$ for all $k>0$ and $x$ has no period.

Case 2c: If $f(x) <x$ And the cases 2ci-2ciii are done exactly as above.

Case 2ci: $f_2(x) = x$ and $x$ has period $2$.

Case 2cii:$x > f_2(x) > f(x)$ we conclude $x > f_n(x)$ for all $n$.

Case 2ciii  If $f(x) < x < f_2(x)$ then $f_{2k-1}(x) < x < f_{2k}(x)$ for all $k > 0$.

Comment: You could perhaps use more simply that $f_2(x)$ is increasing in case $2$ and applying case $1$ to $f_2$ then gives the result since a periodic point of $f$ is also a periodic point of $f_2$.

Comment: You know.... I could have.   And I should have.  But I didn't think of it.